# Counting Active Directory Security group members

Tags: .net, active-directory, wmi, directoryservices

First, I have to enumerate all the AD groups of the current user. Getting the SID and the name is easy:

```
foreach(var group in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups)
{
   var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(group.Value);
   string name = (group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount).Value;
}
```

Then I need to determine the number of members in each of the groups, and I can't get that to work. I guess I need a way to get the distinguished name of the groups of the current users. Any idea how to get that?

What I did so far: I tried a **WMI** query like this, but it returns no results because I would need the fully qualified domain name but `NTAccount` gives me only the "friendly" domain account (DOMAIN\group):

```
SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser 
WHERE (GroupComponent = "Win32_Group.Domain='somedomain', Name='somegroup'")
```

Then I tried **LDAP**, working around the missing path/Distinguished Name by binding to the SID of the group:

```
var adGroupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", group.Value));
if (adGroupEntry != null)
{
  IEnumerable members = adGroupEntry.Invoke("Members", null) as IEnumerable;
  if (members != null)
  {
    foreach (object member in members)
    {
      noOfMembers++;
    }
  }
}
```

It finds the group, the name property returns the correct value, however `Members` never contains any elements. If I would know the full LDAP path for a group (like when I hard-code it), the code above would actually yield the correct number of users in the group.

What am I missing here? I'm not very familiar with Active Directory or WMI.

Restrictions:

- I can't hard-code any domain names or LDAP paths.
- I'm limited to .NET 2.0, so I can't use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro your problem in my environment.  It sounds like a bug in ADSI to me.

The returned COM object doesn't work if you are using [serverless binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SID binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the same time.

I could workaround that by not using serverless bindnig.  i.e. using this `LDAP://*yourdomain.com*/<SID={0}>` instead

I could also workaround that by binding the object again.

```
var adGroupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>",group.Value));
string dn = adGroupEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value as string;
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dn);
if (de != null)
{
    IEnumerable members = de.Invoke("Members", null) as IEnumerable;
    if (members != null)
    {
        foreach (object member in members) 
        {
            noOfMembers++;     
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for testing my code and the workaround! It actually fixed the issue for me, too :)I didn't expect to be able to get the distinguished name from the properties, as the typed property for this info didn't contain useful content in QuickWatch.